# My INSERT prepared statement is making multiple records with PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to fill mysql table with data from text files. This is the code:

```
try
{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:server=localhost;dbname=pure","root");
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $que=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO posts (title,actress,body,image,date,slug) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Error!";
}
$titles=fopen("titles.txt","r");
$names=fopen("names.txt","r");
$dates=fopen("dates.txt","r");

for($i=0;$i<382;$i++)
 {
    $title=fgets($titles);
    $name=fgets($names);
    $body="<h3 style='text-align:center'>$title</h3>something $name something.<br>Video link<br>Info:";
    $src="images/".str_replace(' ','_',$title).".jpg";
    $date=fgets($dates);
    $slug=str_replace(' ','-',$title);
    $que->execute([$title,$name,$body,$src,$date,$slug]);
    echo "$i done!<br>";

 }
fclose($titles);
fclose($names);
fclose($dates);
echo "DONE!";
?>
```

First, I tested for only 10 - 20 records, and it worked fine. But when I execute the script for all 382 records, in the end, I get 764 records... $i is echoed only 382 times (as it should), so I have no idea why is $que->execute() happening 764 times. Also, It is weird that I get exactly 2x times records, but not all records from text files get into database. Some are inserted for 2 or 3 times, and some are missing.
Anyone has any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would sugest that you first `bindParam()` and then `execute()` the statement. It might fix the error but I'm not sure.

Edit:
If you're using PDO then you would use `bindParam()`
like this: 
 `$que->bindParam(...);`

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Could you please tell me why? :D I don't understand, why the example in my question makes multiple INSERTS, and 100% same code with bind parametars doesn't?

Comment: How could `bind_param()` possibly solve the question? What was posted was PDO. `bind_param()` is a MySQLi_ function, not PDO.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: @Mayado20 Impossible.

Comment: well, I don't know what to tell you,.. it's working.

Comment: I was actually talking about `$que->bind_param()` but if  the regular bind_param() works then great.

Comment: When you use `bind_param()` it binds the values to the query and you execute the    query with `execute()`, but when you just execute the query without using `bind_param()` it acts unpredictably and in your case it started repeating queries.

Comment: `bind_param()` is MySQLi_ api. On the other hand and it resembles it, the PDO syntax is `bindParam()` without the underscore. I don't see why what was accepted is valid. What is it that I didn't get/grasp?

Comment: I finally see what you were talking about Funk Forty Niner. I didn't even notice that Leon wrote bind_param with underscore, I just tried PDO's bindParam, and it worked. Thanks for commenting back, I was actually about to post new question asking about bindParam in PDO :D And also, Leon Kunstek, thanks for help and explanation.
Edit: Leon Kunstek, you should edit your answer to $que->bindParam() to erase the confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I didn't notice what I wrote as the answer. I've fixed it now.